# How to fill a pandas dataframe in a list comprehension?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

I need to fill a pandas dataframe in a list comprehension.

Although rows satisfying  the criterias are appended to the dataframe.

However, at the end, dataframe is empty.

Is there a way to resolve this?

In real code, I'm doing many other calculations. This is a simplified code to regenerate it.

```
import pandas as pd

main_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c','d'])
main_df=main_df.append({'a':'a1', 'b':'b1','c':'c1', 'd':'d1'},ignore_index=True)
main_df=main_df.append({'a':'a2', 'b':'b2','c':'c2', 'd':'d2'},ignore_index=True)
main_df=main_df.append({'a':'a3', 'b':'b3','c':'c3', 'd':'d3'},ignore_index=True)
main_df=main_df.append({'a':'a4', 'b':'b4','c':'c4', 'd':'d4'},ignore_index=True)
print(main_df)

sub_df = pd.DataFrame()
df_columns = main_df.columns.values

def search_using_list_comprehension(row,sub_df,df_columns):
    if row[0]=='a1' or row[0]=='a2':
        dict= {a:b for a,b in zip(df_columns,row)}
        print('dict: ', dict)
        sub_df=sub_df.append(dict, ignore_index=True)
        print('sub_df.shape: ', sub_df.shape)

[search_using_list_comprehension(row,sub_df,df_columns) for row in main_df.values]

print(sub_df)
print(sub_df.shape)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you define an empty frame with `sub_df = dp.DataFrame()`  then you assign the same variable within the function parameters and within the list comprehension you provide always the same, empty sub_df as parameter (which is always empty). The one you append to within the function is local to the function only. Another “issue” is using python’s `dict` variable as user defined. Don’t do this.

Here is what can be changed in your code in order to work, but I would strongly advice against it

```
import pandas as pd

df_columns = main_df.columns.values

sub_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df_columns)

def search_using_list_comprehension(row):
    global sub_df
    if row[0]=='a1' or row[0]=='a2':
        my_dict= {a:b for a,b in zip(df_columns,row)}
        print('dict: ', my_dict)
        sub_df = sub_df.append(my_dict, ignore_index=True)
        print('sub_df.shape: ', sub_df)

[search_using_list_comprehension(row) for row in main_df.values]

print(sub_df)
print(sub_df.shape)
```

Comment: Is there a way to add rows to pandas dataframe in a list comprehension without using "global" keyword?